# Include image on wordpress site and update site when image gets overwritten

Tags: php, html, wordpress, server

I'm designing a WordPress Site right now, and want to include a webcam to give users the possibility to see the live weather. Therefore a picture from the webcam is uploaded to the wordpress webspace under `wordpress/wp-content/uploads/webcam/upload.jpg` every 5 minutes.

I now want to include this picture (which changes every 5 minutes but always has the same name) on my website.

Currently I'm using simple html to include the picture:

`<img class="alignnone size-medium" src="https://XXXXXXX.de/wp-content/uploads/webcam/upload.jpg" width="1280" height="720" />`

I can see a picture on the website, but when the image on the server gets overwritten, the website still shows the "original" picture.

How can I achieve a that a user who logs onto the site always sees the newest version of the picture on the server? As I said, the name of the file is always the same.

I'm using the [impreza](https://themeforest.net/item/impreza-retina-responsive-wordpress-theme/6434280) theme if this is important.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to add some js to change url of the img like           `document.querySelector('#image2').src = 'https://XXXXXXX.de/wp-content/uploads/webcam/upload.jpg?time=' + (new Date()).getTime();`

Comment: @Felox Where exactly can I implement js on a WordPress site? And is '#image2' a specific tag which I need to provide for the image as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a get param to make browser understand it is a new URL and it will fetch. e.g use src attribute something like
src="https://XXXXXXX.de/wp-content/uploads/webcam/upload.jpg?your_Ver_var=currenttimeoutput()"
Implement currenttimeoutput() or use inbuilt php time method to render it